# Does having more non-searchable retrievable fields reduce azure search performance?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have included maximum possible fields while creating the search index to be safe in case I need to retrieve those fields in future. Many fields are not currently searchable and retrievable. Does having more fields not retrievable, searchable, filterable, sortable and facetable in Index reduces the search performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both indexing and search will be affected by having more fields. Obviously, the less features those fields support the less work the indexer has to do. If the field is only retrievable you only have to store that data. If it's searchable you have to build the index.

As an example, I tested the same data with 2 fields and 1000 fields. Indexing performance went from around 1300 documents per second to 30 documents per second. I'm expecting the total amount of data to have the biggest effect on indexing performance.

The query performance is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you saying there will not be any affect on search performance? Only indexing performance will go down?

Comment: Can you please share some link if you have any reference. Thanks

Comment: This post would be it, I'm afraid. I have tested my data systematically and collected performance numbers as I increase the complexity of the data model. If you transfer data with 1000 fields, but none of those fields are searchable, filterable, sortable, or retrievable your overhead is merely the transfer of that data. As soon as you ask the search engine to process that data, by defining a field as searchable for example, the processing overhead increases.

Comment: I found this bit of official documentation that confirms the conclusion here. 

"The schema of your index plays an important role in indexing data. Adding fields and adding additional properties to those fields (such as searchable, facetable, or filterable) both reduce indexing speeds."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-large-index#index-schema